# trouble aligning pictures for mobile sites

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm a beginner coder and just finished my first website for my music group. It looks great on desktops.

Check it out! grnbrier.com

On mobile the pictures are all messed up.

[incorrect image placement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJjFz.png)

Here's my code for it. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong or any way to make it look better on mobile phones?

```html
<style>
    body {
        background-color: black
    }
    .image-margin {
        margin-left: 525px;

    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<center> 
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/WEnPPlD.png" alt="Logo" width="400" height="300" >
</center>
<a href="https://grnbrier.bigcartel.com/"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/sHPjLDi.png" onMouseover="this.src='https://i.imgur.com/CV7ElQf.png';" onMouseout="this.src='https://i.imgur.com/sHPjLDi.png';" class="image-margin" width="200" height="200" title="clothing" alt="Clothing"></a>
<a href="https://www.soundcloud.com/love_seat"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/QdrtoZ6.png" onMouseOver="this.src='https://i.imgur.com/XrlDin7.png';" onMouseOut="this.src='https://i.imgur.com/QdrtoZ6.png';" width="200" height="200" title="music" alt="Music"></a>
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/grnbrier/"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/x5POgmB.png" onmouseover="this.src='https://i.imgur.com/qRTlMh2.png';" onmouseout="this.src='https://i.imgur.com/x5POgmB.png';" width="200" height="200" title="socialmedia" alt="Socialmedia"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the margin left you have set to your first image using `.image-margin` class. It's not only on mobile it does not look centered, it happens also in other resolutions different to the one you are using to design it.

You could try and wrap your images in a `div` element. Then you can set a `display: flex` property to that div and then start playing around with the aligment and justify properties.

For instance:

```
<div class="my-flex-div">
  <a href="#"><img src="myimage.jpg/></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="myimage.jpg/></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="myimage.jpg/></a>
</div>
```

And then your style would be:

```
.my-flex-div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

I recommend [this article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) in order to learn more about flex.

Then in order to make it look nice on mobile you can start using media queries.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .my-flex-div {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

Have a look to [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) regarding media queries.

Try start playing around with this stuff, and you'll get much nicer results.

Comment: Hey! thanks for your help. i replaced the code and now it looks like https://i.imgur.com/vGgQGN0.png on the desk top and https://i.imgur.com/Wo2qQ37.png on mobile. it looks better! any way i can make them be closer to each other and center them on the mobile version?

Comment: I can't reproduce it the way you see it. I have replicated your site in this link: https://codepen.io/ejelicich/pen/RwPXVex. I have added the align-items: center property to the div containing the images inside the media query. Check it out